Can I read sensor data in the background on React Native?
I am trying to develop an application for reading the native accelerometer/sensor readings from a device when the app is either in the background or terminated altogether (ideally at a frequency of 5-10Hz). I am able to get foreground sensor readings with expo-sensors but I'm unable to find a solution/ library that works when the app is in the background/locked/terminated.
My questions are as follows:

Is this possible at all with React Native and what are the limitations of proposed approaches?
If it is possible, how frequently will iOS and Android allow you to take sensor readings in the background before shutting down your application for being too battery hungry?

I've tried using expo-sensors library.
